# django app for loop: views.py or frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, django, frontend

I am building a Django app that has a list of words. The app now tells the user the first word of the list via a speech function. Then the user can record an audio of a word he says. This word gets turned into a string in the front end. Now I want to compare the word from the user with the first string of a second list that has the same amount of characters as the first list. And this whole process should be repeated with all characters of the first list.
Can I do this kind of loop in my views.py or would it work better in the frontend in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it on the frontend in javascript by using an async function, which awaits another function to return a Promise.
For more details check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65995332/javascript-function-gets-ignored-in-loop) post.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, you can loop inside your views.py, inside your function make a loop and can compare your words.

Comment: But how should the function in views.py then know when to take  the next character in the list